# How to extract a sentence from a text file in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, while-loop, ifs

I have a book in text format. which I converted from pdf using pdftotext. and I want to extract a random sentence from a file. keep in mind the sentence might have a return character at the end of the line. so I want to find a way to get the reminder of the sentence in the next line. So I guess the problem will be to get the start of the sentence. Usually, a capital letter. "^[A-Z]" and then get everything to the next '.' I have tried things like

```
grep "^[A-Z].*.$" text.txt
```

but that doesn't work.
Also tried using IFS and assigning the '.' as the separator. but I'm getting the full file printed out to screen. it will be helpful if I can print full sentence one per line.

```
IFS=.
while read sentence; 
do 
    echo $sentence
done < the-prince.txt
```

Comment: Try `grep -Poz "^[A-Z][^.]*" text.txt` if you have GNU grep

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you forgot dot in regex for the end of sentence `\.`.

Comment: @Raffi Maybe, the `.` before `$` is not escaped, but if OP meant a literal `.`, yes, the dot can be consumed with `\.`.

Comment: @Raffi you guys are right . means a character in regex... but still that leaves me with the fact that I need a random sentence from the file. This will give me the first sentence

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I still need a random sentence from the file..

Comment: Don't forget that capital letter and dot can be there in the middle of a sentence as well e.g. `I have a friend named Mr. Smith`

Comment: @anubhava good point.. any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

First, a very rough example in perl.

```
#!/bin/perl
$/='. ';
while (<>) { push(@_, $_) if /^[A-Z]/; }
print $_[rand @_], "\n";
```

It does not account for questions, exclamations, or quotations, or the `Mr. Something` problem, nor will it intelligently format sentences with embedded newlines.

There are other problems, but this should at least get you started if perl is an option.

For pure bash, if that's what you need, I'll have to look a little more.